# Trying to get death and respawn working in my game

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I can't get my respawning in my game to work, I have followed numerous tutorials, but have been failing to change one small aspect of them. I have a health variable in my game, and all the tutorials have the player die and respawn right upon touching the enemy. I want it to be so you take damage when touching an enemy, and when your health reaches 0 you are brought to a game over scene. I just can't seem to figure it out. I am new to game dev so I have tried my absolute hardest to solve the problem on my own, but to no avail. This is pretty much my last resort. I appreciate any help I can get.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{

public static PlayerHealth instance;

public int maxHealth;
public int health;
public int GameOver;


public event Action DamageTaken;


public int Health
{
    get
    {
        return health;
    }
}


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake()
{
    

    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }
}

private void Start()
{
    health = maxHealth;
}

// Update is called once per frame
public void TakeDamage()
{
    if(health <= 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    health -= 1;
    if(DamageTaken != null)
    {
        DamageTaken();
    }
}

public void heal()
{
    if (health >= maxHealth)
    {
        return;
    }
    health += 1;
    if (DamageTaken != null)
    {
        DamageTaken();
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        TakeDamage();
    }

    if(health <= 0)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(GameOver);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When health is <= 0 you should probably run the code that makes the player die instead of just using return which isn't triggering anything to happen from what I can tell.

Comment: What's your current state? I guess health reaches zero but it does nothing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your code specifically. It could be a different issue in the editor, which is usually the case. To debug try one of the following:

1. Check that the OnCollisionEnter is actually being triggered
2. Check that the Enemey has the Enemy Tag.

You can check 1 & 2 with the following code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    // Check what the tag is
    print(other.gameObject.tag); 
    ...
}
```

There should now be messages when you run the program.  Other things to check:

3. Make sure the player object has the PlayerHealth script attached to it.
4. Make sure that the player has a RigidBody
5. Make sure the enemy has a collider
6. Make sure the enemy collider is not set to `Trigger`

Comment: So after checking everything and making sure it is all as you said it should be I added the code. I am not getting anything in the console that shows me that the function is working, any ideas why that might be